# Upgrade to Windows Server 2012 from Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

Trying to upgrade Windows Server from 2008 R2 to 2012.  On compatibility check throwing an error

```
Active Directory on this domain controller does not contain Windows Server 2012
ADPREP /FORESTPREP updates. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=113955.
```

As per the suggested above link did what required; but still throwing same error.

Any helps?

Comment: Is there another DC?

Comment: @Nev - just a comment, why so quick to leap into this version, it's VERY new.

Comment: @Chopper3 especially on a DC *shudder*

Comment: Did you do both a domain prep and a forest prep? Have you raised the functional level of the forest and the domain to 2008?

Comment: @ChrisMcKeown  Uh, you can't raise a functional level above the oldest DC on the forest/domain.  So that's not going to help him when he can't get all this DCs up to 2012.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Fully aware of that, but where does Nev state that he has any pre-2008 DCs on the network?

Comment: Not really necessary to raise it to 2008 though, I see that 2012 supports a functional level of 2003.

Comment: @gravyface: no there's only one DC.

Comment: @ChrisMcKeown: Yes functional level both forest/domain are raised to 2008 R2.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is whether you ensured that the user account running the adprep/forestprep was a member of the Schema Admins group.

Comment: @Chris Mckewon: Yes the user was a memeber of the Schema Admins group.

Answer (score 7):

@Nev, I had the same error. The Microsoft link suggest to use the Windows 2008R2 disc, however the updates are on the 2012 disc. For me the solution was to perform the Microsoft solution with the Windows 2012 disc and reboot. The same goes for the ADPREP /DOMAINPREP updates.

Comment: +1 for this answer - I did not need to reboot though.

Answer (score 7):

Just `cd` to `support\adprep` on the Windows 2012 media and run:

```
adprep /forestprep
adprep /domainprep
```

Comment: I can confirm this also works for the Windows Server 2016 to Windows Server 2019 in-place upgrade. I couldn't `cd` into the ISO, so I had to unpack it to disk first, then `cd` into it and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You run `adprep /forestprep` *from* from 2012 media *on* the DC holding the Schema Master role in your forest. Then, you run `adprep /domainprep` and `adprep /gpprep` *from* the 2012 media *on* the DC holding the Infrastructure Master role in the domain that you're putting the 2012 DC in.

Comment: is adprep /gpprep needed?

Comment: @dataCore it wasn't for me

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that if the error still appear after doing the
adprep /forestprep
adprep /domainprep
It could be a problem in replication between the DCs (which was in my case) so also check the replication