# Trouble Upgrading Secondary DC from 2008R2 -> 2012R2 without FSMO Roles Present

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, upgrade

I am attempting to upgrade a recovered DC running 2008R2 to 2012R2. This DC is the secondary and the primary is still in production. When attempting the upgrade process, I run into an issue where the upgrade complains on the compatibility check. The error I receive is this:

SETUP cannot determine if Windows Server 2012 R2 ADPREP /FORESTPREP and /DOMAINPREP updates exist on this domain controller. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=141481 .

Further context:

This has been recovered to a VM in ESXi and has no network connectivity as we don't want it showing up in our RMM dashboard twice and causing confusion (amongst other reasons), so I am bypassing the upgrade check in the beginning of the upgrade process.

The only thing I've found and attempted is this: https://serverfault.com/a/430666

However, I am unable to do those steps because all of the FSMO roles reside on the primary DC.

So, my question is:

Is there any way for me to complete this upgrade process without the FSMO roles being on the secondary DC or having direct connectivity between the 2 DC's via same subnet/enabling internet connectivity.

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

Comment: This is an offline test, why not seize the roles? If you want the upgrade to resemble reality, the schema needs to be either: a) already updated, which is usually a benign process, or 2) it needs to be updated (assuming that there is an updated schema). Can't update the schema without the schema role owner.

Comment: @GregAskew How can I accomplish this without having access to the DC that holds those roles?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/transfer-or-seize-operation-master-roles-in-ad-ds